# AdControl is errored in windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8.1

I drag AdControl from toolbox and set XAML code as

```
<UI:AdControl AdUnitId="Image320_50" ApplicationId="test_client"
                          Grid.Row="2" AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="30" IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

but in error list show: "AdControl is not supported in a Windows Phone project".
How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it from here

I double click adcontrol on toolbox to generate some things and it's ok.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ae41070-d796-4e2e-aacb-94241b5f8b3c/adcontrol-is-not-supported-in-a-windows-phone-project?forum=aiaforwinphone